# Spring MVC : Redirecting to login when user trying to access secure resource

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

- I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I send out emails
  to which contain links for a @RequestMapping which inturn tries to
  access a resource which is under ROLE_USER.

  - The problem is, I want to redirect user to login page at /login
    directly if he/she tries to access any secure resource. I tried to
    search for something similar, but couldn't find any exact match. I am
    pasting my security-application-context.xml. Kindly have a look.

  ```
  <!-- Global Security settings -->
  <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
  <security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>

  <security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
      <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/canvas/list" always-use-default-target="false" authentication-failure-url="/denied.jsp"  />
      <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" user-service-ref="userDetailsService" token-validity-seconds="1209600" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
      <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
      <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/login"/>

  <security:port-mappings>
      <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>
  </security:port-mappings>
      <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login"/>
  </security:http>

  <!-- queries to be run on data -->
  <beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
      <beans:property name="key" value="_spring_security_remember_me" />
      <beans:property name="tokenRepository" ref="jdbcTokenRepository"/>
      <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
  </beans:bean>

  <!--Database management for remember-me -->
  <beans:bean id="jdbcTokenRepository"
              class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
      <beans:property name="createTableOnStartup" value="false"/>
      <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  </beans:bean>

  <!-- Remember me ends here -->
  <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="LoginServiceImpl">
         <security:password-encoder  ref="encoder"/>
      </security:authentication-provider>
  </security:authentication-manager>

  <beans:bean id="encoder"
              class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
      <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
  </beans:bean>

  <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
              class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
              <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
             <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
  </beans:bean>
  ```

Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to provide an `<intercept-url>` element in `<security-http>`. Right now spring security isn't securing any urls.

You'll also need to add `<session-management>` to your configuration and specify the `invalid-session-url` attribute.

Try taking a look at the spring documentation:

[`<intercept-url>` info](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-minimal)

[`<session-management>` info](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-session-mgmt)

When the user attempts to access a secured resource, they should be redirected the the login page.

Comment: Yes. I had removed it for testing as our site operates on https, and I dont have SSL Key on localhost. We have it like this, <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https"/> . This takes the entire website under https, which is the requirement.